# SQLAlchemy - Add different order_by condition to a relationship in query eager_load

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, relationship, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model and a relationship defined to the model itself (Parent-Child). There is an order_by property set to the relationship in the model. Like below:

```
from app import db

class ModelA(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'activities'
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   startdate = db.Column(db.Date())
   sort_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
   parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('activities.id'))
   children = db.relationship("ModelA", cascade="all,delete-orphan", backref=db.backref('parent', remote_side=[id]),order_by='ModelA.sort_id')
```

Now, I have query to fetch all records in ModelA with its children eagerloaded. Only thing is, in this specific query, the children have to be ordered based on startdate instead of sort_id. The query is given below

```
a_alias = aliased(ModelA)
activities = ModelA.query.outerjoin(a_alias, ModelA.children).options(
                     contains_eager(ModelA.children, alias=a_alias)).filter(ModelA.projectId == project_id).\
                     order_by(nullsfirst(ModelA.parent_id), ModelA.startdate, a_alias.startdate).all()
```

But, this **query does not sort** the children relation that is eager-loaded with startdate. It still sorts based on sort_id defined in the model. What should I do to overcome this ?

Comment: why this query is so special? why don't you manually add `order_by` in other places (including this one)?

Comment: Have you loaded the ModelA objects and their children before in this same session?

Comment: @IljaEverilä Good point. I will have to check it.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov All features require the children to be sorted based on sort_id and thats why the relationship has the property defined. But this is a special case.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks for the comment. The issue is solved. It was because the relationship was getting loaded in the same session.